# In the statement $\text dV = 4\pi x^2\text dx$ , how is the radius $x^2\text dx$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, integration, calculus

I was recently studying a question based on Electrostatics. Here is the link to the question (along with the answer below). I haven't learned integration yet. But my question here is how did we get $x^2\text dx$ as the radius of the Gaussian shell?

Link to the question and answer: https://www.sarthaks.com/40525/let-there-be-a-spherically-symmetric-charge-distribution-with-charge-density

Comment: *I haven't learned integration yet.*  This seems to be the thing you need to do.  Basic integration isn't hard and that's all you'll need.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2dx$ is not radius here. $4\pi x^2$ is the surface area of the spherical surface, multiplying by $dx$ gives you the differential volume.

Comment: Thank you, Brother. If you don't mind, whenever you are free, could tell me how exactly the concept of differential volume is used here? What I meant is could you kindly elaborate on that part of the answer and how we derive upon the conclusion of x^2dx. I haven't taken.

Comment: $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi x^3$, differentiating we get, $dV = 4 \pi x^2 dx$

Comment: @Mechanic Ahhhh Thanks:)

Comment: @Hrishi why do you think $x^2dx$ would be the radius, looking by dimension clearly it is not.